# bedtools: get name column of alignment file A

Tags: read-mapping, bedtools

I'm using the `coverage` function of `bedtools` to check whether a certain set of regions (file B) has any overlap with known regions of epigenetic markers (file A). When that is the case, I want to access the name of that marker, which is given as the third column (name) in file A.

However, when I run `bedtools coverage -a fileA.bed -b fileB.bed`, I only get the columns of file B as an output, together with the overlap fraction. Is there a built-in way of accessing also the columns of the file A to which I aligned, or an easy way of cross-referencing to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [bedtools intersect](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html) for that type of comparison.  This will allow you to see the specific segments that overlap.  bedtools coverage is used more for determining how many things cover a region but not which ones.

The documentation linked above will provide a much better desciption of intersect than I would be able to in this post but I would recommend using the `-loj` or `-u` depending on what you want.

```
-loj    Perform a “left outer join”. That is, for each feature in A report each overlap with B. If no overlaps are found, report a NULL feature for B.

-u  Write original A entry once if any overlaps found in B. In other words, just report the fact at least one overlap was found in B. Restricted by -f and -r.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with `fileB.bed` (a [sorted](https://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/file-management/sorting/sort-bed.html) BED file) and `fileA.txt` (a three-column text file, where the name is in the third column), then you could pipe single-base pseudo-BED elements to [`bedmap`](https://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/statistics/bedmap.html).

```
$ bedmap --echo --echo-map-id --delim '\t' fileB.bed <(awk -vFS="\t" -vOFS="\t" '{ print $1, $2, ($2+1), $3 }' fileA.txt) > answer.bed
```

The `--echo-map-id` option reports the list of marker IDs from `fileA.txt`, where the single-base marker interval from `fileA.txt` overlaps a region in `fileB.bed`.

If all the marker IDs are not unique (if there are duplicate marker IDs) it may make sense to instead use `--echo-map-id-uniq`.

This assumes that marker positions in the second column and that the intervals in `fileB.bed` are using a 0-based index scheme. If marker positions are 1-based and `fileB.bed` is 0-based, then a small adjustment is needed to make both inputs use the same indexing, to calculate correct overlaps:

```
$ bedmap --echo --echo-map-id --delim '\t' fileB.bed <(awk -vFS="\t" -vOFS="\t" '{ print $1, ($2-1), $2, $3 }' fileA.txt) > answer.bed
```

I mention this, as SNVs (such as those from VCF) can often be reported with a 1-based index scheme, which adds some nuance to doing set operations against BED files.